# User device authentication offline

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I am developing an offline Winforms app in C# which uses localDB. It will be sold to a few people in a company, who can run the app on 1 device per person. I would like to prevent them from passing the app to any other person or device. Is there a way to do that? (Authenticating after the first launch should be enough.)

Comment: Make the first run create a Key based on some distinct values (combining the CPU, main HD serial number etc.), generate a Key that a User need to communicate via mail or phone. You generate an Activation Key using the provided Key and pass this Activation Key to the User to activate the Program. It's easily cracked (just a `NOP`or two in the right place), but you have to know how to crack a program.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!